# How do I download Firefox's new "No restart" add-ons?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I want to download the Firefox's new "No Restart" plugins without having to install them. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: So you want to download them, but not install them?

Comment: Yes. That what I want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you search using Mozilla's website ([addons.mozilla.org](https://addons.mozilla.org/)), you should be able to download any add-on by right-clicking the `Add to Firefox` button and selecting `Save Link As`.

To install the addon, you can then simply drag the file from your desktop or file browser to the Firefox window.